# Sorting and filtering ExtJS headerless grid

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have a grid that doesn't have header. The requirement is to sort the grid manually. I have a list of columns in a combobox and radio buttons to specify column name and sort direction respectively. How can I sort that grid on a button's click? Similarly how can I hide/show columns in the same grid using the same approach(selecting columns from a list and clicking a button)?

Answer (score 1):

There are API methods you can call for both your tasks.

For sorting, mind that sorting is done by store, not by grid. You can find relevant methods in [Ext.data.Store](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) documentation - search for keyword 'sort'.

For columns manipulation, you would get the column from items collection of [Ext.grid.header.Container.items](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.header.Container-property-items) and then you would call show or hide method on that column.